# Prevent google map polygon from editing.

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a drawing tool in my google map for drawing polygons.

right now when I draw a polygon I see circles around it that make the polygon editable.

[image]

Is there a settings to draw a polygon and have it fixed in the map I mean not able to be edited.

My code:

```
// Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw Polygons
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingControlOptions: {
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
            ]
        },
        polygonOptions: polyOptions,
        map: map
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `editable`, `draggable` and `clickable` attribute of polygon options. Set all of them to `false` and you won't me able to edit, drag and not even click the polygon. If you want to allow clicking you can leave that at `true`.

```
polyOptions: {
   clickable: true,
   draggable: true,
   editable: true,
   //there can be other option like fillColor, fillOpacity...
}
```

Comment: If my answer helps with your issue please accept/upvote it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that :)